# extracting users Arabic name using Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex

i have a problem in extracting Arabic name, i've used the lookbehind method:

```
name=re.search(r"(?<=MR)\s\D\w+",H,re.M|re.I)
```

where H is the string,when i used it with MR it work perfectly!!
but the problem is when i changed it to "اسمي" which is " may name" in Arabic
it does not find the name

Answer (score 1):

If you want shorthand character classes (`\w`, `\W`, `\b`, `\B`, `\d`, `\D`, `\s` and `\S`) to be Unicode-aware, use `re.U` (or `re.UNICODE`):

```
name = re.search(r"(?<=اسمي)\s\D\w+", H, re.U)
```

`re.M` flag is redundant here, since it only affects `^` and `$`.

`re.I` flag is redundant here, since Arabic characters don't have the concept of uppercase/lowercase.

Comment: `U` flag only changes the behavior for shorthand character classes like `\w`, `\d`. It is not necessary if the regex doesn't have those shorthand character classes. Also, `M` and `I` flags are unnecessary in your regex

Comment: Thank you for the help.. But i've tried your suggestions and it didn't work :( !!